# How can I do order by without using it in group by

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called products and I would like to get all my products with same asin inside one row and concat their skus in one column I came up with something like this but I have problem with order by sku and other columns that are not inside group by. Is there any solution?

my sql:

```
SELECT prod.asin, string_agg(p.sku,', ') AS skus,
  SUM(p.amazon_inv_available) AS amazon_available_inv,
  SUM(p.amazon_inv_total) AS amazon_total_inv
FROM (
  SELECT id, asin, sku, amazon_inv_available, amazon_inv_total
  FROM products 
  WHERE store_id IN (12, 10, 11)
  ORDER BY sku
) AS prod
LEFT JOIN products AS p  ON prod.asin = p.asin
GROUP by prod.asin
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=030763bbcdcb859936f2eb5926255db1)

Desired result when order by prod.sku

[image]

order by prod.sku DESC

[image]

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: Please add the expected result to the question, not as a comment.

Comment: @Serg Added my desired output

Comment: @TheImpaler Added my desired output

Comment: @MjEbrahimzadeh I added the new answer. You need to order by `id` while concatenating skus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `ORDER BY` to `STRING_AGG()` to specify the ordering of the concatenated values.

For example:

```
SELECT
  asin, 
  string_agg(sku,', ' order by id) AS skus,
  SUM(amazon_inv_available) AS amazon_available_inv,
  SUM(amazon_inv_total) AS amazon_total_inv
FROM products
WHERE store_id IN (12, 10, 11)
GROUP by asin
ORDER BY amazon_available_inv
```

Result:

```
 asin  skus        amazon_available_inv  amazon_total_inv 
 ----- ----------- --------------------- ---------------- 
 B     HH, QW      200                   400              
 A     AC, TT, DD  300                   600
```

See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=fa302c2870640a5d372997645ce83f9c).

Comment: tnx, How can I order by amazon available inv?

Comment: @MjEbrahimzadeh Added the ordering.

Comment: Btw order by sku I meant p.sku thats the reason I did left join because of that.

Answer (score 4):

You can use order by inside `string_agg(sku,', ' order by sku)` and remove order by from your subquery

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution. I used my query as subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT prod.asin, string_agg(p.sku,', ' ORDER BY p.sku) AS skus,
SUM(p.amazon_inv_available) AS amazon_available_inv,
SUM(p.amazon_inv_total) AS amazon_total_inv
FROM (SELECT id, asin, sku, amazon_inv_available, amazon_inv_total
FROM products WHERE store_id IN(
10,11,12)) AS prod
LEFT JOIN
products AS p
ON prod.asin = p.asin
GROUP by prod.asin) AS res
ORDER BY skus
```